# How can I export TIFF images to JPEG with no adjustments, using Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, jpeg, scanning, tiff, scanning-service

I use Lightroom (version 3 now, probably 4 soon) to work with my raw images. When exporting to JPEG, Lightroom applies a number of adjustments, even if I leave all the settings at the default.

This is correct for raw images, but I'm now having a bunch of prints and slides scanned to TIFF, and the scanning service will do basic adjustments for me. I'd like to store the TIFFs in Lightroom so I can keyword and organize them, but when I export, I don't want Lightroom to do anything to the image other than convert the TIFF to JPEG. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what settings you see Lightroom apply. There are options for sharpening and resizing, for example, but those are right there in the Export dialog so I presume you mean something else that is non-obvious, but I don't know what adjustments you're referring to.

Comment: @Dan, for example in raw there is a default camera profile which among other things fiddles with the curves (or something like that -- I'm not near my computer to check).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware the only adjustments Lightroom does when exporting are those that are selected in the Export dialog. You can turn all of these off within the dialog (and can create a preset so you don't have to do it again in the next export by clicking the 'Add' button under the list of presets on the left).

The only adjustable setting that can't be turned off for JPEGs is the quality slider which is usually recommended to be set to between 70-76  to achieve the best tradeoff between visible quality and file size, [this page](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/jpeg-quality) has an extensive discussion with examples, of the effects of the various quality 'ranges' that Lightroom will save JPEGs in.